# Learning BEM for CSS

Tags: css, sass, bem

I'm looking and learning and implementing BEM into my company front-end framework using SASS.

Does it take a while for you to learn and implement its methodology?

I can see its benefits as I'm building a large application.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I've recently started using BEM for a work project and it has been an excellent experience learning so far. I highly recommend using it starting on a new project and it is easy to pickup and it is a massive improvement on code quality and abiding by some standards on how to style a new component or module of your application.

### Why use BEM (Block Element Modifier)?

> BEM stands for **Block**, **Element**, and **Modifier**. BEM was
> created as an approach to front-end development designed with the
> flexibility and ease of modification in mind. The main idea of BEM
> methodology is to speed development process up and ease the teamwork
> of developers. It is an abstract way to think about your design
> without relying on HTML structure. BEM captures purpose and meaning
> through it’s CSS classname syntax.

### Block

> A block is a component on your page that may be reusable and will hold
> elements inside of it. Examples of a block would be a header, menu or
> an image. A block can contain elements and other blocks.

### Element

> An element is something that will only ever exist inside the block. It
> depends on the block to exist. Examples of an element would be a
> header sub-title, menu item or image captions. An element can contain
> other elements and modifiers.

### Modifier

> A modifier defines the appearance and behavior of either a block or an
> element. The modifier indicates a state difference from the default.
> Examples would be themes, active/inactive states or aligning.

Example:

```
.block {}
.block__element {}
.block--modifier {}
.block__element--modifier {}

.nav {}
.nav__item {}
.nav--footer {}
.nav__item--active{}
```

BEM has helped in being able to easily breakdown a design and find "elements" and "modifiers" for a Block within a design. BEM can also be applied to any project size small or large. Avoiding nesting also makes it easier to make adjustments to modules without breaking other inner parts of functionality. Code quality is also improved as the developer would think twice before adding in a hack css selector just to get something right.

My team also uses SMACSS "Scalable and Modular Architecture for CSS" along with BEM to split out our SASS into a number of modules. This allows to easily find a components styling without having to search through a massive long stylesheet. It makes new developers life easier to find styling and reading code. Again it is scalable for all project sizes.

You can read more on combining BEM and SMACSS here - [Combining BEM and SMACSS](https://thesocietea.org/2016/06/combining-bem-and-smacss/).

Once you make the change you will wonder how you used to build projects. It makes styling a project much more straight-forward and less stressful with clean and modular code.

Comment: BEM is great if you like having hundreds of classes with ridiculously long names.

Comment: Not really its quiet the opposite actually. If your code is modular then it becomes very clear where and what CSS classes do just by reading the name and structure of the class rather than guess work of what selectors are suppose to do with writing css without a standard format. Sometimes poorly written CSS can contain all of the styling for a particular element within one css selector whichmakes code ugly and doesn't support reuse. BEM makes the user to split code into smaller parts for reuse. It also discourages large amounts of nesting and id tags which are problematic on large projects.

Comment: I am not suggesting writing unstructured CSS. Far from it. I am suggesting writing well-structured CSS without all the conceptual overhead, profusion of classes, and long class names of BEM, much of the motivation for which is an unfounded concern over performance.

Comment: Writing well-structured CSS across the whole project becomes difficult to maintain when in a team though. BEM makes the developer think about writing the class in the best / most reusable way possible that isn't nested with other parts of the site. Its also great to use in larger team and project environments to keep quality consistent. BEM also helps in reducing the cause of side effects when changing one component. Since using BEM it has greatly improved my sass code quality and structure along with SMACSS.